# Heroku not running gulp?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, heroku

I just posted my app onto heroku but for some reason the app is crashing because gulp is not found. Gulp runs fine locally but not on heroku.
[Heroku log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SArQg.png)

[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdKDh.png)

Let me know if any other files are essential

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8Aku.png This is my gulp file as well
Not sure what the herokuproduction does but I saw someone post something like that online

Answer (score 1):

Heroku defaults to skipping devDependencies. Either move gulp to production dependencies or run this: `$ heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false` for Heroku to use dev configs.

More info here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process

Side note: the "heroku-production" is simply a task name within the gulpfile. You don't seem to have a task with that name.